# providing dummy apis in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there a way I can create some dummy APIs with dummy response in WSO2 API Manager? Our API implementation is not yet ready.Till its ready , can we create an API and give some sample json as response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best thing would be using the API manager to create API using prototype option.

1. Create API
2. Add entries for design screen
3. On the implementation screen choose - Prototyped API
4. Choose Implementation Method as inline for JSON (it will not work for 
       SOAP)
5. in Resource section click on any of the method types lets say Get
6. add the java script to mock the json data
   /*    mc.setProperty('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json');
                  `enter code here`mc.setPayloadJSON('{ "data" : "sample JSON"}');*/
       /*   Uncomment the above comment block to send a sample response.*/
7. Publish it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create prototype API. please let me know if this help.
Refer following document [Deploy and Test as a Prototype](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Deploy+and+Test+as+a+Prototype)

Answer (score 0):

If your servers has internet access, you can use http://www.mocky.io/ to mock your response. When you are creating an API in WSO2 API Manager provide the url of the mocky.io as the endpoint.